# Sending Bithday SMS to user mobile in Laravel and Birthday, Anniversary sms Text message setting in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How we can send Birthday and Anniversary sms with settings like we can create multiple SMS to be triggered and number of days before birthday or anniversary with message text in user mobile using Laravel Framework??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel Using Cronjobs You can easily do that by just making a SMSController like (Here we are using two tables clients and sms_settings)
The Code is:

```
class SMSController extends Controller{


 public function test(Request $request){

 $date =Carbon::now(); //current system date now

 $date = $date->format('m/d');

  // For Birthday SMS

  $schedule = DB::table('sms_settings')->select('scheduled_type','number_of_days')->where('occasion','Birthday')->get();    
  foreach($schedule as $key=>$results){
  $number_of_days = $results->number_of_days;
  $scheduled_type = $results->scheduled_type;


   // select clients with dob 

    if($scheduled_type=='Before'){



  $required_date  = Carbon::now()->addDays($number_of_days);

    }

  if($scheduled_type=='After'){



  $required_date  = Carbon::now()->subDays($number_of_days);

      }




 $required_month = $required_date->format('m');
 $required_day = $required_date->format('d');

 $req = $required_month."-".$required_day;




 $results = DB::table('clients')->select('dob','mobile','first_name','last_name')->where('dob','LIKE','%'.$req.'%')->get();

 $r1 = DB::table('clients')->select('dob','mobile','first_name','last_name')->where('dob','LIKE','%'.$req.'%')->first();




 if(!$r1=null)
  {  
foreach($results as $key=>$result)
 {

   $dob = $result->dob;
  $mobile_list = $result->mobile;
  $first_name = $result->first_name;
  $last_name = $result->last_name;
  // dd($mobile_list);




   $a =   DB::table('sms_settings')->select('message_header','message')->where('occasion','Birthday')->get();


    foreach($a as $key=>$results){
    $header = $results->message_header;
    $mbody = $results->message;
       }

   $message_text = $header." ".$first_name.","."\n". $mbody;



$authKey = urlencode('Your Auth Key');
// Message details
$mobiles = array($mobile_list);
$sender = urlencode('123456');
$message = rawurlencode($message_text);
$route=2;
$country=5;

$mobiles = implode(',', $mobiles);


// Prepare data for POST request
$data = array('authkey' => $authKey, 'mobiles' => $mobiles, "message" => $message, "sender" => $sender,"route" =>$route,"country" =>$country );

// Send the POST request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('your url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process your response here

}

// Execute it via performing cronjobs




  }

 }
```

// For Anniversary SMS Follow same steps as above

And Finally You have to enter your Cron entry to your server and call to it by targetting the schedule methode on Kernel.php file in Laravel as :

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){

$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\SMSController@test')->everyMinute();

 // Perform your task every minutes.

  }
```